# Story ID, blue planet/sun, ice ring, spider aliens, possibly man named Ty

Tags: story-identification

When I was in primary school, around 1999, I read a story with a plot, as I remember, that is as follows:

A blue gas planet or blue sun with a vast ice ring around it has been discovered, and a mission is sent to explore it that vanishes without a trace. A new mission is sent, lead possibly by a man called Ty, of whom the main character is jealous. When they arrive at the planet they are attacked by spider-like alien creatures who live on the ice ring.

It may have been a novel, or perhaps a short story in an anthology. I read it in Australia.

Comment: I feel like I remember this as a short story, also read in primary school.  Spiders living on the ice ring is what triggered my memory.  Calling it a novel seems a stretch; can you remember more about when you read it?